# Spring boot test does not run in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing

I have a `ConnectionException` problem when I run the spring boot tests with the command `./gradlew clean test`

The interesting point is that the tests are successfuly running in Intellj (even with the gradle runner set up as default). And totally don't work in gradle (always Connection Refused). I added some sections after reading about similar problems (they are marked with `//added`).

What else can i configure?

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)// added
class CommercialUnitLevelIT extends BaselineDbTestSetup {

 @BeforeAll
 static void init() {//added
    RestAssured.port = 8080;
 }

 @BeforeEach
 void setUp() {
    //some set up
 }

 @Test
 ///my testcase 
 }
}
```